# Generic method with HttpMethod as a parameter

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a method that will invoke other methods based on the HttpMethod.
My method looks like this:

```
public async Task<string> CreateAsync<T>(HttpClient client, string url, HttpMethod method, T data, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    switch(method)
    {
        case HttpMethod.Post:
            return await PostAsync(client, url, data);
        case HttpMethod.Put:
            return await PutAsync(client, url, data);
        case HttpMethod.Delete:
            return await DeleteAsync(client, url, parameters);
        default:
            return await GetAsync(client, url, parameters);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the switch is moaning about this:

> A constant value is expected

And each case is underlined in red.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `HttpMethod.Post` and all the others are not constants which is what switch statement expects. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpMethod.cs) for example you will see why. You can use a strategy pattern to solve this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it was already pointed out the problem is that the `HttpMethod` `Delete`, `Post`, ...etc. properties are instances and not constants or enums. It was also pointed out that they are equatable.

The only thing I would like to add is that if this is C# 7 you can use pattern matching instead of the *if..else if....else if...* chain:

```
public async Task<string> CreateAsync<T>(HttpClient client, string url, HttpMethod method, T data, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    switch (method)
    {
        case HttpMethod m when m == HttpMethod.Post:
            return await PostAsync(client, url, data);
        case HttpMethod m when m == HttpMethod.Put:
            return await PutAsync(client, url, data);
        case HttpMethod m when m == HttpMethod.Delete:
            return await DeleteAsync(client, url, parameters);
        default:
            return await GetAsync(client, url, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: R# says : https://i.imgur.com/Hn3uUFQ.jpg.. and suggest  : https://i.imgur.com/1lD91Xo.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You could not do that like dasblinkenlight and Nkosi said. The easiest work around is to use `HttpMethod.Method` and hard-coded string for case statement.

```
public async Task<string> CreateAsync<T>(HttpClient client, string url, HttpMethod method, T data, Dictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    switch (method.Method)
    {
        case "POST":
            return await PostAsync(client, url, data);
        case "PUT":
            return await PutAsync(client, url, data);
        case "DELETE":
            return await DeleteAsync(client, url, parameters);
        default:
            return await GetAsync(client, url, parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since static properties of `HttpMethod`, such as [`HttpMethod.Put`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod.put(v=vs.118).aspx) and [`HttpMethod.Post`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod.post(v=vs.118).aspx), are instances of `HttpMethod` class, you cannot use them as case expressions in a `switch` statement, as if they were members of an `enum`.

These objects are equatable, though, so you can use them in a chain of if-then-else, or in a `Dictionary<HttpMethod,SomeDelegate>` where `SomeDelegate` is an action type representing the task that you would like to run:

```
if (method == HttpMethod.Post) {
    return await PostAsync(client, url, data);
} else if (method == HttpMethod.Put) {
    return await PutAsync(client, url, data);
} else if (method == HttpMethod.Delete) {
    return await DeleteAsync(client, url, parameters);
} else {
    return await GetAsync(client, url, parameters);
}
```